# How to use xlwings debug server in word vba (or vbscript)

Tags: python, vba, com, pywin32, xlwings

How to use xlwings debug server from microsoft word vba.

What I want, is to make UDF in microsoft word using xlwings server.

Is this even possible?

Currently I am understanding win32, python and vba so that I can write xlwings like utility for vba in general.

```
import xlwings

xlwings.serve()
xlwings server running, clsid={506E67C3-55B5-48C3-A035-EED5DEEA7D6D}
```

Question is, how to use this running server from vba (or vbscript)?